# Unstable data from XML mapping from a correct XML Dataset from Business central

Tags: ms-word, dynamics-business-central

Thanks in advance if you can help me with this behaviour!

[image: Attributes not shown] (image links on the bottom of this question)

Included: images and the XML code to reproduce this issue. The Word-document you make it on your own, with the Development module - XML mapping pane.

From Business central support reponse: I made additional research and contact our production team for conformation. According to them XML Mapping is a Word feature which is outside of the control of BC.

If you run the word document with this data, the only the Item_Attr_Name appears; or only the Item_Attr_Value appears. Or you see nothing.

I tried already a lot of things.
-From time to time the data values Item_Attr_Value appears

[image: example 2]

-In other cases, from a similar dataset the values are disappeared.
![image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsot0.png)]

-Maybe not relevant, if I remove the object in word, then also it's removed in XML mapping panel? See
image[image: XXmJh]

-Made an RDL file with Report builder there's the data as in the dataset.

Hereunder a copy of the dataset from Business Central: when I run a RDL report from this data the data appears correctly.

```
<ReportDataSet name="1 Order Confirmation" id="51305">
  <DataItems>
    <DataItem name="Header">
      <Columns>
        <Column name="CompanyAddress1">ABC</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyAddress2">No adress street</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyAddress3">9999 </Column>
        <Column name="CompanyAddress4">Belgique</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyAddress5"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyAddress6"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyAddress7"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyAddress8"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyHomePage"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyEMail"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyPicture"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyPhoneNo"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyPhoneNo_Lbl">Tél.</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyGiroNo"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyGiroNo_Lbl">Giro No.</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyBankName"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyBankName_Lbl">Banque</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyBankBranchNo">01</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyBankBranchNo_Lbl">Code établissement</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyBankAccountNo"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyBankAccountNo_Lbl">Account No.</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyContactPerson_Lbl">Personne à contacter</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyContactPerson">Mr. S</Column>
        <Column name="Contact_Lbl">Des questions ?</Column>
        <Column name="Sell_to_Email_Lbl">Sell to email</Column>
        <Column name="Sell_to_E_Mail">notused@abc.be</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyShipToAddress_Lbl">Notre adresse de livraison</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyShipToAddress1">Entrepôt</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyShipToAddress2">Rue de la livraison 123</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyShipToAddress3">9999 </Column>
        <Column name="CompanyShipToAddress4">Belgique</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyShipToAddress5"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyShipToAddress6"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyShipToAddress7"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyShipToAddress8"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyIBAN_Lbl">IBAN</Column>
        <Column name="CompanySWIFT_Lbl">Code SWIFT</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyLogoPosition">0</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyRegistrationNumber"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyRegistrationNumber_Lbl">N° de société</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyVATRegNo"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyVATRegNo_Lbl">N° de société</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyVATRegistrationNo"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyVATRegistrationNo_Lbl">N° de société</Column>
        <Column name="CompanyLegalOffice"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyLegalOffice_Lbl"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyCustomGiro"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyCustomGiro_Lbl"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyLegalStatement"></Column>
        <Column name="CustomerAddress1">ADM. </Column>
        <Column name="CustomerAddress2">RUE DU CENTRE 1080</Column>
        <Column name="CustomerAddress3">9990</Column>
        <Column name="CustomerAddress4">Belgique</Column>
        <Column name="CustomerAddress5"></Column>
        <Column name="CustomerAddress6"></Column>
        <Column name="CustomerAddress7"></Column>
        <Column name="CustomerAddress8"></Column>
        <Column name="CustomerPostalBarCode"></Column>
        <Column name="YourReference"></Column>
        <Column name="YourReference_Lbl">Votre référence</Column>
        <Column name="ShipmentMethodDescription"></Column>
        <Column name="ShipmentMethodDescription_Lbl">Mode d'envoi</Column>
        <Column name="Shipment_Lbl">Note d'envoi</Column>
        <Column name="ShipmentDate">22/02/21</Column>
        <Column name="ShipmentDate_Lbl">Date de préparation</Column>
        <Column name="ShowShippingAddress">True</Column>
        <Column name="ShipToAddress1">ECOLE COMMUNALE PRIM.</Column>
        <Column name="ShipToAddress2">MME BERNARDETTE</Column>
        <Column name="ShipToAddress3">HEIRBAAN 15</Column>
        <Column name="ShipToAddress4">9990</Column>
        <Column name="ShipToAddress5">Belgique</Column>
        <Column name="ShipToAddress6"></Column>
        <Column name="ShipToAddress7"></Column>
        <Column name="ShipToAddress8"></Column>
        <Column name="PaymentTermsDescription">30 JOURS FIN DE MOIS</Column>
        <Column name="PaymentTermsDescription_Lbl">Conditions de paiement</Column>
        <Column name="PaymentMethodDescription"></Column>
        <Column name="PaymentMethodDescription_Lbl">Payment Method</Column>
        <Column name="DocumentCopyText">Confirmation vente</Column>
        <Column name="BilltoCustumerNo">ABC.COMMUNALE.</Column>
        <Column name="BilltoCustomerNo_Lbl">N° Client</Column>
        <Column name="DocumentDate">22/02/21</Column>
        <Column name="DocumentDate_Lbl">Date</Column>
        <Column name="DueDate">31/03/21</Column>
        <Column name="DueDate_Lbl">Date d'échéance</Column>
        <Column name="DocumentNo">CC-21-00019</Column>
        <Column name="DocumentNo_Lbl">N° document</Column>
        <Column name="QuoteNo"></Column>
        <Column name="QuoteNo_Lbl">N° devis</Column>
        <Column name="PricesIncludingVAT">False</Column>
        <Column name="PricesIncludingVAT_Lbl">Prix TTC</Column>
        <Column name="PricesIncludingVATYesNo">Non</Column>
        <Column name="SalesPerson_Lbl">Vendeur</Column>
        <Column name="SalesPersonText_Lbl">Vendeur</Column>
        <Column name="SelltoCustomerNo"></Column>
        <Column name="SelltoCustomerNo_Lbl">N° donneur d'ordre</Column>
        <Column name="VATRegistrationNo"></Column>
        <Column name="VATRegistrationNo_Lbl">N° de société</Column>
        <Column name="GlobalLocationNumber"></Column>
        <Column name="GlobalLocationNumber_Lbl"></Column>
        <Column name="SellToPhoneNo"></Column>
        <Column name="LegalEntityType"> </Column>
        <Column name="LegalEntityType_Lbl">Type partenaire</Column>
        <Column name="Copy_Lbl">Copy</Column>
        <Column name="EMail_Lbl">Email</Column>
        <Column name="HomePage_Lbl">Website</Column>
        <Column name="InvoiceDiscountBaseAmount_Lbl">Invoice Discount Base Amount</Column>
        <Column name="InvoiceDiscountAmount_Lbl">Invoice Discount</Column>
        <Column name="LineAmountAfterInvoiceDiscount_Lbl">Payment Discount on VAT</Column>
        <Column name="LocalCurrency_Lbl">Local Currency</Column>
        <Column name="ExchangeRateAsText"></Column>
        <Column name="Page_Lbl">Page</Column>
        <Column name="SalesInvoiceLineDiscount_Lbl">Ristourne %</Column>
        <Column name="Invoice_Lbl">Confirmation vente</Column>
        <Column name="Subtotal_Lbl">Sous-total</Column>
        <Column name="Total_Lbl">Total</Column>
        <Column name="VATAmount_Lbl">Montant TVA</Column>
        <Column name="VATBase_Lbl">VAT Base</Column>
        <Column name="VATAmountSpecification_Lbl">Montant TVA Specifié</Column>
        <Column name="VATClauses_Lbl">VAT Clause</Column>
        <Column name="VATIdentifier_Lbl">VAT Identifier</Column>
        <Column name="VATPercentage_Lbl">VAT %</Column>
        <Column name="VATClause_Lbl">Clause TVA</Column>
        <Column name="ShowWorkDescription">False</Column>
        <Column name="ShipToAddress_Lbl">Adresse de livraison</Column>
        <Column name="ClientNumber">1000</Column>
        <Column name="SalesPersonBlank_Lbl">Vendeur</Column>
        <Column name="SaleAgentName">LMF</Column>
        <Column name="SaleAgentEMail"></Column>
        <Column name="SaleAgentPhone">0</Column>
        <Column name="ExternalDocumentNoCaption">N° doc. externe</Column>
        <Column name="CustomerNoCaption">N° donneur d'ordre</Column>
        <Column name="ResponsibleCaption">Code vendeur</Column>
        <Column name="ReferenceCaption">Votre référence</Column>
        <Column name="Reference"></Column>
        <Column name="SalesHeaderDocumentNo">CC-21-00019</Column>
        <Column name="ExternalDocumentNo">BC:22 ARTICLE: 12322/25-02</Column>
        <Column name="SalesHeaderSellToCustomerNo">ABC</Column>
        <Column name="SalesHeaderSalesPersonCode">FLE</Column>
        <Column name="CustomerContactCaption">Contact donneur d'ordre</Column>
        <Column name="CustomerContactName">ABC FLE</Column>
        <Column name="CustomerContactFirstName"></Column>
        <Column name="CustomerContactMiddleName"></Column>
        <Column name="CustomerGSMNoCaption">N° téléphone donneur d'ordre</Column>
        <Column name="CustomerGSMNo"></Column>
        <Column name="CustomerPhone"></Column>
        <Column name="CustomerEMailCaption">E-mail</Column>
        <Column name="CustomerEMail"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanyIBAN"></Column>
        <Column name="CompanySwift"></Column>
        <Column name="DocumentTitle_Lbl">Confirmation vente</Column>
        <Column name="Bank_Lbl">Compte bancaire</Column>
        <Column name="IBAN_Lbl">N° compte international (IBAN)</Column>
        <Column name="BICCode_Lbl">BIC</Column>
        <Column name="Bank0">CPH</Column>
        <Column name="IBAN0">BE92xxxxxxxxxx</Column>
        <Column name="BIC0"></Column>
        <Column name="Bank1"></Column>
        <Column name="IBAN1"></Column>
        <Column name="BIC1"></Column>
        <Column name="Bank2"></Column>
        <Column name="IBAN2"></Column>
        <Column name="BIC2"></Column>
        <Column name="Bank3"></Column>
        <Column name="IBAN3"></Column>
        <Column name="BIC3"></Column>
        <Column name="ConditionsText"></Column>
        <Column name="QuoteBeginLine"></Column>
        <Column name="QuoteEndLine"></Column>
        <Column name="HeadQuarterLbl">Siège social</Column>
        <Column name="BilltoCustumerName">ABC9999 </Column>
        <Column name="BilltoCustomerName_Lbl">Nom</Column>
        <Column name="ContactLbl">Contact</Column>
        <Column name="BillToName_Lbl">Adresse de facturation</Column>
        <Column name="CustomerPicture"></Column>
      </Columns>
      <DataItems>
        <DataItem name="Line">
          <Columns>
            <Column name="LineNo_Line">10000</Column>
            <Column name="Description_Line">ARMOIRE AXEDIS -1970-1200-0420</Column>
            <Column name="Description_Line_Lbl">Désignation</Column>
            <Column name="ItemNo_Lbl">N° article</Column>
            <Column name="VREF_Lbl">Votre n° article</Column>
            <Column name="Qty_Lbl">Qté</Column>
            <Column name="Price_Lbl">Price</Column>
            <Column name="ItemPicture"></Column>
          </Columns>
          <DataItems>
             <DataItem name="Item_Attribute_Values">
               <Columns>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Name">Hauteur Produit</Column>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Name_CurrLang">Hauteur Produit</Column>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Value">1970</Column>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Value_CurrLang">1970</Column>
               </Columns>
             </DataItem>
             <DataItem name="Item_Attribute_Values">
               <Columns>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Name">Longueur Produit</Column>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Name_CurrLang">Longueur Produit</Column>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Value">1200</Column>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Value_CurrLang">1200</Column>
               </Columns>
             </DataItem>
             <DataItem name="Item_Attribute_Values">
               <Columns>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Name">Profondeur produit</Column>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Name_CurrLang">Profondeur produit</Column>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Value">420</Column>
                 <Column name="Item_Attr_Value_CurrLang">420</Column>
               </Columns>
             </DataItem>
           </DataItems>
          <DataItem name="VATAmountLine">
          <Columns>
            <Column name="InvoiceDiscountAmount_VATAmountLine" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">0</Column>
            <Column name="InvoiceDiscountAmount_VATAmountLine_Lbl">Montant remise facture</Column>
            <Column name="InvoiceDiscountBaseAmount_VATAmountLine" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">123,00</Column>
            <Column name="InvoiceDiscountBaseAmount_VATAmountLine_Lbl">Montant base remise facture</Column>
            <Column name="LineAmount_VatAmountLine" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">234,00</Column>
            <Column name="LineAmount_VatAmountLine_Lbl">Montant ligne</Column>
            <Column name="VATAmount_VatAmountLine" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">49,14</Column>
            <Column name="VATAmount_VatAmountLine_Lbl">Montant TVA</Column>
            <Column name="VATAmountLCY_VATAmountLine" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">49,14</Column>
            <Column name="VATBase_VatAmountLine" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">234,00</Column>
            <Column name="VATBase_VatAmountLine_Lbl">Base TVA</Column>
            <Column name="VATBaseLCY_VATAmountLine" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">234,00</Column>
            <Column name="VATBaseLCY_VATAmountLine_Lbl">VAT Base (LCY)</Column>
            <Column name="VATIdentifier_VatAmountLine">M3</Column>
            <Column name="VATIdentifier_VatAmountLine_Lbl">Identifiant TVA</Column>
            <Column name="VATPct_VatAmountLine" decimalformatter="#,##0.#####">21</Column>
            <Column name="VATPct_VatAmountLine_Lbl">% TVA</Column>
            <Column name="NoOfVATIdentifiers">1</Column>
          </Columns>
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem name="ReportTotalsLine">
          <Columns>
            <Column name="Description_ReportTotalsLine">Sous-total</Column>
            <Column name="Amount_ReportTotalsLine" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">234,00</Column>
            <Column name="AmountFormatted_ReportTotalsLine">234,00</Column>
            <Column name="FontBold_ReportTotalsLine">True</Column>
            <Column name="FontUnderline_ReportTotalsLine">False</Column>
          </Columns>
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem name="ReportTotalsLine">
          <Columns>
            <Column name="Description_ReportTotalsLine">TVA 21%</Column>
            <Column name="Amount_ReportTotalsLine" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">49,14</Column>
            <Column name="AmountFormatted_ReportTotalsLine">49,14</Column>
            <Column name="FontBold_ReportTotalsLine">False</Column>
            <Column name="FontUnderline_ReportTotalsLine">True</Column>
          </Columns>
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem name="LetterText">
          <Columns>
            <Column name="GreetingText">Hello</Column>
            <Column name="BodyText">Thank you for your business. Your order confirmation is attached to this message.</Column>
            <Column name="ClosingText">Sincerely</Column>
            <Column name="PmtDiscText"></Column>
          </Columns>
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem name="Totals">
          <Columns>
            <Column name="TotalNetAmount" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">234,00</Column>
            <Column name="TotalVATBaseLCY" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">234,00</Column>
            <Column name="TotalAmountIncludingVAT" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">283,14</Column>
            <Column name="TotalVATAmount" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">49,14</Column>
            <Column name="TotalVATAmountLCY" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">49,14</Column>
            <Column name="TotalInvoiceDiscountAmount" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">0</Column>
            <Column name="TotalPaymentDiscountOnVAT" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">49,14</Column>
            <Column name="TotalVATAmountText">TVA 21%</Column>
            <Column name="TotalExcludingVATText">Total EUR HT</Column>
            <Column name="TotalIncludingVATText">Total EUR TTC</Column>
            <Column name="TotalSubTotal" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">234,00</Column>
            <Column name="TotalSubTotalMinusInvoiceDiscount" decimalformatter="#,##0.00">234,00</Column>
            <Column name="TotalText">Total EUR</Column>
          </Columns>
        </DataItem>
      </DataItems>
    </DataItem>
  </DataItems>
</ReportDataSet>
```